# What does the Chrome "Aw, Snap! Error code: 11" refers to?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm working on a page with a dozen of HTML5 videos playing one after another and randomly get this "Aw, Snap! Error code: 11".

Everything works fine on other browsers, but I can't find any information on this specific error code 11 on Chrome.
I tried debugging it on Mac with the following but no error showed up:

```
log stream --level debug --predicate 'processImagePath contains "Google"'
```

Do you have please any idea of what Code 11 means in order to narrow my research ?

Comment: So much empty! Did you ever get an answer @Matt Sparrer ?